# TextView getLineCount()*getLineHeight() != getHeight()

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to get the exact Y position of a given line of text. I thought I would use `i * TextView.getLineHeight()` to get the Y position of the ith line, but that doesn't seem to be right.

The reason I think this is wrong is because `TextView.getLineHeight() * TextView.getLineCount() != TextView.getHeight()` which I assume is due to the same error. The line spacing and line multiplier are both default for this TextView.

What is the proper method to get the y position of the ith line in a TextView?

EDIT ---

It seems even `TextView.getLayout().getLineTop(i)` isn't correct, although please tell me if I'm overlooking something

Comment: you need the Y position corresponding to the TextView or to the Full display of the device?

Comment: @abdulrahmank y pos relative to the textview

Comment: does `TextView#getLineBounds` work correctly?

Comment: @Bob any luck with this?

Comment: @Gagan I found a different way to solve my problem, but couldn't find a solution to do this

Comment: @Bob Pretty strange that something as basic as this is quite tricky to achieve, if at all :(

Answer (score 0):

```
private int getTextViewHeight(TextView textView) {  
    Layout layout = textView.getLayout();  
    int desired = layout.getLineTop(textView.getLineCount());  
    int padding = textView.getCompoundPaddingTop() + 
    textView.getCompoundPaddingBottom();  
    return desired + padding;  
}
```

This code is helped.Read the TextView SourceCode(about onMeasure) you can know how it worked.